# Is it possible to view PDFs right in Chrome without downloading them first?

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, pdf

When I click a link to a PDF in Chrome instead of displaying the PDF in the browser I see a blank page with "Missing plugin" written over it. Is it possible to get this plugin somewhere or am I condemned to downloading the PDF first and then displaying it using standard PDF viewing software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google have [recently released](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/bringing-improved-pdf-support-to-google.html) this feature for Chrome, however there are currently several bugs associated with it, especially on Linux. This feature will come, but may take time (anything from days to months, though Chrome is usually quite good at fixing such problems).

Alternatively you could use the official [Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en) to automatically view PDF files in Google Documents.

[image: Google Documents PDF Virwer]

Answer (score 1):

You might be seeing [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49702), which should be fixed in a newer release of Chrome. I use the [Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn) which sends the PDF directly to google docs to view.

Comment: I also used that alternative, the thing is that half the time I only get like a code instead of the document :/. Is there a way to fix that?